# Can i wrap a dto using only lombok features?

Tags: java, json, lombok, objectmapper

I have a dto class for interaction with payment system api:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentSystemRequestDto {
    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    protected String orderId;
    @JsonProperty("merchant_id")
    protected String merchantId;
    @JsonProperty("amount")
    protected Long amount;
    @JsonProperty("currency")
    protected String currency;
    @JsonProperty("version")
    protected String version;
    @JsonProperty("verification")
    private Boolean verification = false;
    @JsonProperty("verification_type")
    private VerificationType verificationType;

    public static class PaymentSystemRequestDtoBuilder {
        public PaymentSystemRequestDtoBuilder amount(Long amount) {
            this.amount = amount * 100;
            return this;
        }

        public PaymentSystemRequestDtoBuilder cardRegistrationPayment() {
            this.verification = true;
            this.verificationType = VerificationType.AMOUNT;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm sending a request, based on my dto i have such a post method body:

```
{
    "order_id": "a94f1d0d-21c5-4c2d-824d-d6c1875eaa30",
    "merchant_id": "1234567",
    "amount": 100,
    "currency": "USD",
    "version": "1.0",   
}
```

I need to wrap the body into "request" object, so the body look like:

```
{
    "request": {
        "order_id": "a94f1d0d-21c5-4c2d-824d-d6c1875eaa30",
        "merchant_id": "1234567",
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "USD",
        "version": "1.0",   
    }
}
```

but without modification of object mapper serialization / deserialization features (**not using annotation @JsonRootName**)

I've tried to create an inner class with a builder, but it seems robust and complex... Is there any way to handle this simple?

Comment: Can't you create a `Map<String, PaymentSystemRequestDto>` and serialize it instead of the plain `PaymentSystemRequestDto` object?

Comment: I consider this as not quite safe and convenient solution...

Comment: Instead of the map, you could use a trivial single field class; anyway, I find the map pretty fool-proof and simple.